# Swift 2 - performBatchUpdates - Animate cell one by one when visibile inside the UICollectionView frame

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, swift2

I am trying to animate each cell of my `UICollectionView` visibile in the frame.
Every time I scroll a new cell appears with the animation.

I am doing this using `performBatchUpdates` inside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` however, the animation is applied to all cells at the same time and its very fast. It seems that the animation of 1 second its not recognised.

Also I am trying to find the way to apply an animation to a cell when a button is pressed with no success.

The code I use is:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let Cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellClass

    self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
                        Cell.layer.cornerRadius = 200
                        return
                        }){
                            completed in

                            UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: {
                                Cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                            })
                        }

    Cell.playAnimationBtn.layer.setValue(indexPath.row, forKey: "indexPlayBtn")
}

@IBAction func actionGetAnimation(sender: UIButton)
{
    let indexUser = (sender.layer.valueForKey("indexPlayBtn")) as! Int

    //Cell selected do animation corners = 200
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make this work when you move the animation to `willDisplayCell(_:cell:indexPath:)`. That method is called every time a new cell is about to be displayed.

You cannot use `UIView.animateWithDuration` for the layer properties. You have to use `CABasicAnimation` for that.

If you want to animate the cell when the user presses a button you can call `animateCellAtIndexPath` from the code example below. You have to know the cell's indexPath to do so. In this example I call this method when the user selects the cell.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    animateCell(cell)
}

func animateCell(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "cornerRadius")
    animation.fromValue = 200
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 0
    animation.toValue = 0
    animation.duration = 1
    cell.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
}

func animateCellAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) else { return }
    animateCell(cell)
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    animateCellAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is helping me a lot. However, I confused in writing my question. Is there a way to animate the button pressed and not the view?

Comment: What attribute of the Button do you want to animate?

Comment: You can animate your button's alpha in your custom `CellClass`. To animate the alpha you can use `UIView.animateWithDuration`

Comment: Thanks, I cannot find the way to tell the CellClass the button to have the animation. If i press all of them start animate

Comment: The `IBAction` that you connect to the button has to be in the `CellClass` not in the view controller.

Comment: Thank you! if I move the `IBAction` to `CellClass` it works and just the button pressed get alpha 0.1. However, if I scroll the view I can see that other buttons got the alpha changed

Comment: In your `CellClass` you have to implement `prepareForReuse()` and set the alpha of the button back to its default value.