# Swift ReloadData NSCollectionView Animated

Tags: macos, animation, reloaddata, nscollectionview

How can I update my `NSCollectionView` with new item animated? Updating the collection view work fine but it looks shabby without animation...

```
func updateParameterCollectionView(){

    //NSAnimationContext.current().duration = 0.5 ???
    parameterCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({ () -> Void in
   // here you can insert ,delete and animate cells
}) { (success) -> Void in    
   //completion block
}
```

Comment: ok, I implemented the `performBatchUpdates` but there is still no animation. Could you add some more informations?

Comment: Review this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522296/swift-2-performbatchupdates-animate-cell-one-by-one-when-visibile-inside-the

Comment: I figured out that if you need updates to be animated, you should call it like: `collectionView.animator().performUpdates()`.